# VBA code to insert image to cell based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2021

Dears, I have a worksheet where i need to insert 1 or 2 images from a folder on my pc to the Excel file based on cell value

i need to insert image in cell (H43) based on the value in cell (E5) and the other image in cell (L43) baded on the value in cell (G5) and if E5 or G5 is blank to keep the other cell blank and this is my folder source "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs" N.B. i have all images also created as hyberlinks on other sheet if this will help (I'm using office 2021)

i have found a code on internet but only can insert one image not two please help me as I'm new to the vba code

thank you dears in advance for help and here is the code i have

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim picname As String
Dim pic As Object
Dim source As String

Dim t, l, h, w As Integer

source = Range("H43").Value
picname = "Picture 2"
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes(picname)

With pic
t = .Top
l = .Left
h = .Height
w = .Width

End With

ActiveSheet.Shapes(picname).Delete

Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(source, False, True, l, t, w, h)

pic.Name = picname

End Sub


please modify the code to insert 2 images not one
```

Comment: If there are image URLs available and you're using Excel 365, then you should find the new IMAGE function, described in [IMAGE function - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5), to be easier and better to use. Just several weeks ago, I wrote code for a customer to add multiple images (even up to hundreds of them) to an Excel spreadsheet in various cells using this new function, with this working quite well for him.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm using office 2021 not 365 and image function is not available for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

> if E5 or G5 is blank to keep the other cell blank

I'm assuming you mean if E5 is cleared then make sure Picture 1 doesn't exist and if G5 is cleared then make sure Picture 2 doesn't exist (though a commented out line is included to use if you also want to clear the path values in H43 and L43). [Edit: I just noticed I'm mentioning blank shapes in the text in cells H43 and L43 - I considered then decided against using blanks as placeholders, but forgot to remove the extra text from the cells in the screenprints below; the text should have been something like: 'The path to picture 1 is stored in H43' and 'The path to picture 2 is stored in L43'.]

Let's say we're starting off with the following inside the worksheet:
[image: Initial setup]

Then changing E5 to a non-blank value adds Picture 1 based on the path in H43:
[image: Step 2]

Changing G5 to a non-blank value also adds Picture 2 based on the path in L43:
[image: Step 3]

Similarly, changing the values to blanks, removes the respective:
[image: Steps 4 and 5]

The code prints out the following for the four steps above:
[image: Immediate window]

Here's the code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pic As Shape, a As Variant, r As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Create a 2x3/multidimensional array using the Application.Evaluate [] shortcut.
    a = [{"Picture 1","E5","H43"; "Picture 2","G5","L43"}] 'The array contains pic: names, cond. & path rngs

    For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = a(r, 2) Then
            Debug.Print "Potential edit in sheet: " & ws.Name & " cell: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
            If Target.Value <> "" Then 'delete old pic insert new one
                Debug.Print " Del old if exists & Add the new: " & a(r, 1) & " into cell: " & a(r, 3)
                On Error GoTo AddShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
AddShapeHandler:
                Debug.Print " " & a(r, 1) & " does not exit, a new one will be added"
                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select
                'might be a good idea to check if path is valid/picture file is in the folder
                Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Value, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, -1, -1)
                pic.Name = a(r, 1)
                Exit For
            Else
                Debug.Print " Del old if exists: " & a(r, 1) & " and optionally clear cell: " & a(r, 3)
                On Error GoTo DelShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
DelShapeHandler:
'                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).ClearContents 'uncomment if you want to also delete the path
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's the code with the hardcoded path per your comments below (remember to change picture1.png and picture2.png file names in the array called 'a' if your file names are different):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pic As Shape, a As Variant, r As Long, path As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    path = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    'The array below contains picture names, condition ranges, add-to ranges, _
        and file names for pictures 1 and 2 (e.g. picture1.png - please edit these to match your file names)
    a = [{"Picture 1","E5","H43","picture1.png"; "Picture 2","G5","L43","picture1.png"}] 'Create a 2x4/multidimensional array using the Application.Evaluate [] shortcut.

    For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = a(r, 2) Then
            Debug.Print "Potential edit in sheet: " & ws.Name & " cell: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
            If Target.Value <> "" Then 'delete old pic insert new one
                Debug.Print " Del old if exists & Add the new: " & a(r, 1) & " into cell: " & a(r, 3)
                On Error GoTo AddShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
AddShapeHandler:
                Debug.Print " (Adding a new " & a(r, 1) & ")"
                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select
                'might be a good idea to check if path is valid/picture file is in the folder
                path = path & a(r, 4)
                Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, -1, -1) '-1,-1 simply uses the picture's original Width and Height respectively
                pic.Name = a(r, 1)
                Exit For
            Else
                Debug.Print " Del old if exists: " & a(r, 1) & " and optionally clear cell: " & a(r, 3)
                On Error GoTo DelShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
DelShapeHandler:
                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).ClearContents 'comment-out if you want keep the existing contents in cells H43, L43
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here are the additional updates to the code per your comments below:
[image: screeprints3]

```
'Added a function called picPath for path checking and searching for a picture by name (excluding extension; picture names are hardcoded in the 'a' array)
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pic As Shape, a As Variant, r As Long, path As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    path = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    'The array below contains picture file names without extensions (because extensions may vary), condition ranges, and add-to ranges, _
        (please make sure file names picture001 and picture002 in the array below correspond to the file names in your folder)
    a = [{"picture001","E5","D44"; "picture002","G5","J44"}] 'Create a 2x3/multidimensional array using the Application.Evaluate [] shortcut.

    For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = a(r, 2) Then 'consider using If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5,G5") or Range("E5:G5")) Is Nothing Then...with other changes in the code if you want to change multiple conditions in one swoop
            Debug.Print "Potential edit in sheet: " & ws.Name & " cell: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
            If Target.Value <> "" Then 'delete old pic insert new one
                Debug.Print " Del old if exists & Add the new: " & a(r, 1) & " into cell: " & a(r, 3)
                On Error GoTo AddShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
AddShapeHandler:
                Debug.Print " (Adding a new " & a(r, 1) & ")"
                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select
                path = picPath(path, a(r, 1))
                If Len(path) < 2 Then Exit Sub 'either the path is invalid or the picture wasn't found by name in the array called 'a'
                Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, -1, -1) '-1,-1 simply uses the picture's original Width and Height respectively
                pic.Name = a(r, 1)
                Exit For
            Else
                Debug.Print " Del old if exists: " & a(r, 1) & " and optionally clear cell: " & a(r, 3)
                On Error GoTo DelShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
DelShapeHandler:
'                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).ClearContents 'comment-out if you want keep the existing contents in cells D44, J44
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function picPath(path As String, picName As Variant) As String
    Dim fso, file, files, folder As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then 'Path is valid/folder exists
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
        Set files = folder.files
        If files.Count = 0 Then 'Folder is empty
            Debug.Print " (exiting sub): 0 files in " & path
            picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
        End If
        For Each file In files
            Debug.Print "   (found the following file: " & file.Name & " in " & path & ")"
            If InStr(file.Name, picName) Then 'InStr(look_inside, look_for)
                Debug.Print " ([Success] found: " & picName & " in " & path & ")"
                picPath = file.path: Exit Function 'return picture's path
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print " (exiting sub): Didn't find picName: " & picName & " in " & path
        picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Here's the update per your latest comment (numbers in E5,G5 correlate to picture file names - the code searches the folder from the path String for a file containing the corresponding number in it's name):
[image: screenprint4]
Code:

```
'Essentially only changed 'path = picPath(path, a(r, 1))' to 'path = picPath(path, ws.Range(a(r, 2)).Value)'
'some minor format changes (shape names, Debug.Prints)
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pic As Shape, a As Variant, r As Long, path As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    path = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    'The array below contains picture shape names, condition ranges (numbers in which correlate to picture file names), and add-to ranges
    a = [{"picture1","E5","D44"; "picture2","G5","J44"}] 'Create a 2x3/multidimensional array using the Application.Evaluate [] shortcut.

    For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = a(r, 2) Then 'consider using If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5,G5") or Range("E5:G5")) Is Nothing Then...with other changes in the code if you want to change multiple conditions in one swoop
            Debug.Print "Potential edit in sheet: " & ws.Name & " cell: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
            If Target.Value <> "" Then 'delete old pic insert new one
                Debug.Print " (Del old if exists, Add the new: " & a(r, 1) & " into cell: " & a(r, 3) & ")"
                On Error GoTo AddShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
AddShapeHandler:
                Debug.Print " (Adding the new " & a(r, 1) & ")"
                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select
                path = picPath(path, ws.Range(a(r, 2)).Value)
                If Len(path) < 2 Then Exit Sub 'either the path is invalid or the picture file which name contains ws.Range(a(r, 1)).Value wasn't found
                Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, -1, -1) '-1,-1 simply uses the picture's original Width and Height respectively
                pic.Name = a(r, 1)
                Exit For
            Else
                Debug.Print " (Del old if exists: " & a(r, 1) & " and optionally clear cell: " & a(r, 3) & ")"
                On Error GoTo DelShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
DelShapeHandler:
'                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).ClearContents 'comment-out if you want keep the existing contents in cells D44, J44
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function picPath(path As String, picName As Variant) As String
    Dim fso, file, files, folder As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'consider using dir() instead of fso
    Debug.Print "  [searching for a picture which name contains: " & picName & " in path: " & path & "]"
    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then 'Path is valid/folder exists
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
        Set files = folder.files
        If files.Count = 0 Then 'Folder is empty
            Debug.Print "  [(exiting sub): 0 files in " & path & "]"
            picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
        End If
        For Each file In files
            Debug.Print "   [(found the following file: " & file.Name & " in " & path & ")]"
            If InStr(file.Name, picName) Then 'InStr(look_inside, look_for)
                Debug.Print "  [(success): found a picture which name contains: " & picName & " in " & path & "]"
                picPath = file.path: Exit Function 'return picture's path
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "  [(exiting sub): there is a syntax error in the path or the directory/folder doesn't exist, path: " & path & "]"
        picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Added dynamic resizing of picture shapes if the destination cells are merged. Also added base file name to more accurately/consistently match conditions to picture names:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pic As Shape, a As Variant, r As Long, path As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    path = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    Const base_name_pic = "picture" 'Assuming your picture files are named picture1.jpg, picture2.png and so on
    'The array below contains picture shape names, condition ranges (numbers in which correlate to picture file names), and add-to ranges
    a = [{"picture1","E5","D44"; "picture2","G5","J44"}] 'Create a 2x3/multidimensional array using the Application.Evaluate [] shortcut.

    For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = a(r, 2) Then 'consider using If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5,G5") or Range("E5:G5")) Is Nothing Then...with other changes in the code if you want to change multiple conditions in one swoop
            Debug.Print "Potential edit in sheet: " & ws.Name & " cell: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
            If Target.Value <> "" Then 'delete old pic insert new one
                Debug.Print " (Del old if exists, Add the new: " & a(r, 1) & " into cell: " & a(r, 3) & ")"
                On Error GoTo AddShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
AddShapeHandler:
                Debug.Print " (Adding the new " & a(r, 1) & ")"
                path = picPath(path, base_name_pic, ws.Range(a(r, 2)).Value)
                If Len(path) < 2 Then Exit Sub 'either the path is invalid or the picture file which name contains ws.Range(a(r, 1)).Value wasn't found
                If ws.Range(a(r, 3)).MergeCells Then
                    Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, _
                        ws.Range(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).MergeArea.Address).Width, ws.Range(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).MergeArea.Address).Height)
                Else
                    Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, _
                        ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Width, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Height) '-1,-1 simply uses the picture's original Width and Height respectively
                End If
                pic.Name = a(r, 1)
                Exit For
            Else
                Debug.Print " (Del old if exists: " & a(r, 1) & " and optionally clear cell: " & a(r, 3) & ")"
                On Error GoTo DelShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
DelShapeHandler:
'                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).ClearContents 'uncomment if you want clear the existing contents in cells D44, J44
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function picPath(path, base_name_pic As String, picNum As Variant) As String
    Dim fso, file, files, folder As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'consider using dir() instead of fso
    Debug.Print "  [searching for a picture which name contains: " & base_name_pic & picNum & " in path: " & path & "]"
    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then 'Path is valid/folder exists
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
        Set files = folder.files
        If files.Count = 0 Then 'Folder is empty
            Debug.Print "  [(exiting sub): 0 files in " & path & "]"
            picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
        End If
        For Each file In files
            Debug.Print "   [(found the following file: " & file.Name & " in " & path & ")]"
            If InStr(file.Name, base_name_pic & picNum) Then 'InStr(look_inside, look_for)
                Debug.Print "  [(success): found a picture which name contains: " & base_name_pic & picNum & " in " & path & "]"
                picPath = file.path: Exit Function 'return picture's path
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "  [(exiting sub): there is a syntax error in the path or the directory/folder doesn't exist, path: " & path & "]"
        picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Add date to D11 per your other question:
[image: Date Stamp in D11]

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pic As Shape, a As Variant, r As Long, path As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    path = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\"
    'The array below contains picture shape names, condition ranges (numbers in which correlate to picture file names), and add-to ranges
    a = [{"picture1","E5","D44"; "picture2","G5","J44"}] 'Create a 2x3/multidimensional array using the Application.Evaluate [] shortcut.

    For r = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = a(r, 2) Then 'consider using If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5,G5") or Range("E5:G5")) Is Nothing Then...with other changes in the code if you want to change multiple conditions in one swoop
            ws.Range("D11").Value = Format(ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save time"), "short date")
            Debug.Print "Potential edit in sheet: " & ws.Name & " cell: " & Target.Address(0, 0)
            If Target.Value <> "" Then 'delete old pic insert new one
                Debug.Print " (Del old if exists, Add the new: " & a(r, 1) & " into cell: " & a(r, 3) & ")"
                On Error GoTo AddShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
AddShapeHandler:
                Debug.Print " (Adding the new " & a(r, 1) & ")"
                path = picPath(path, ws.Range(a(r, 2)).Value)
                If Len(path) < 2 Then Exit Sub 'either the path is invalid or the picture file which name contains ws.Range(a(r, 1)).Value wasn't found
                If ws.Range(a(r, 3)).MergeCells Then
                    Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, _
                        ws.Range(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).MergeArea.Address).Width, ws.Range(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).MergeArea.Address).Height)
                Else
                    Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, _
                        ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Width, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Height) '-1,-1 simply uses the picture's original Width and Height respectively
                End If
                pic.Name = a(r, 1)
                Exit For
            Else
                Debug.Print " (Del old if exists: " & a(r, 1) & " and optionally clear cell: " & a(r, 3) & ")"
                On Error GoTo DelShapeHandler
                Debug.Print " (" & ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Name & " exists, deleting)" 'checking if pic exists
                ws.Shapes(a(r, 1)).Delete
DelShapeHandler:
'                ws.Range(a(r, 3)).ClearContents 'uncomment if you want clear the existing contents in cells D44, J44
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function picPath(path As String, picNum As Variant) As String
    Dim fso, file, files, folder As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'consider using dir() instead of fso
    Debug.Print "  [searching for a picture which name contains: " & picNum & " in path: " & path & "]"
    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then 'Path is valid/folder exists
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
        Set files = folder.files
        If files.Count = 0 Then 'Folder is empty
            Debug.Print "  [(exiting sub): 0 files in " & path & "]"
            picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
        End If
        For Each file In files
            Debug.Print "   [(found the following file: " & file.Name & " in " & path & ")]"
            If InStr(file.Name, picNum) Then 'InStr(look_inside, look_for)
                Debug.Print "  [(success): found a picture which name contains: " & picNum & " in " & path & "]"
                picPath = file.path: Exit Function 'return picture's path
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "  [(exiting sub): there is a syntax error in the path or the directory/folder doesn't exist, path: " & path & "]"
        picPath = 0: Exit Function 'return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Dear Igor, I do appreciate the time you have spent to help me - thanks dear

Comment: My pleasure and I'm glad I could help. I'm sure there are better ways to implement the solution, but hopefully this is a good starting point for you to test and debug.

Comment: Dear **Igor** iunfortunately excel doesnt recognize this as a code - Is there is something i have to do first?

Comment: Dears, please I'm still needing your help with a code

Comment: Would you happen to have copied this code into a Module with the intent of using it on multiple sheets? Are you getting any error message (could you post some more details)?

Comment: Actually, yes my workbook has 5 sheets and one of them with has a code also - when i coppied the code to the targeted sheet and try to run it, it doesnt give me any response * I also have a question, there is no source for my images in the code - how it will transfer images from pc to the sheet?   thank you Igor

Comment: my tageted sheet name is "Permit" if this would help

Comment: Could you clarify if you intend to run this code on one sheet or multiple sheets, because if you intend to run it on multiple sheets then there are two approaches you could take, copy paste the code to each sheet (this seems viable since you have only 5 sheets) or, alternatively, implement Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal ws As Object, ByVal Target As Range) in a Module to capture the sheet in which changes are occurring. Let me know which is the case: 1) you're running the code on one sheet only or 2) you want it to work on multiple sheets in your workbook.

Comment: To answer your second question about the "there is no source for my images in the code" - I noticed that in the code in your question you have this line: "source = Range("H43").Value" so the code I posted is using the paths stored in cells H43 and L43 as seen in my screenprints for Pictures 1 and 2 respectively (C:\picture1.png and C:\picture2.png). Let me know if you'd like to include the paths in the code instead.

Comment: thanks first for your interest to help me - this code that I have added in my question I just found it on internet and I only changed the cell number and it worked ok but for only one image while as you know I have 2 images to insert not one. and the images are stored in my pc and this is the path "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs"

Comment: No problem, I added an updated version of the code with the hardcoded path at the bottom of my original answer.

Comment: thank you dear - now I got run-time error 1004 - is there is a way to share my worksheet with you? and can we make the image format not only for png but include jpeg and jpg?

Comment: sure, drop a link in the comments here with the template of your spreadsheet excluding any sensitive data. Also could you tell me on which line the error occurs (I slightly suspect it's on 'Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, ...' because of the jpeg and jpg extensions); and yes. you could include the different extensions and if that's the cause I'll post another update with picture file handling. How do you name the pictures, how many are there in your folder, just trying to think ahead for how to select the correct pictures 1 and 2 in your folder.

Comment: Yes, you are right this is the error line: Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, .. and my images extentions include png-jpg -jpeg - my picture named as numbers 01,02,03 etc.. and i have now 183 images in folder (supposed to be more)  - just simple change in my targeted cells to be "D44" & "J44" instead of H44 & L44 ..... AND here is my file link you can check it and try - (I'm working on "Permit" sheet    (the link: https://file.io/HEZgMmVQKNaq

Comment: Added updated code with lots of comments and printouts to the Immediate window. Hopefully everything makes sense and you're able to make edits as needed (i.e. to picture names, range changes and so on)

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to automate a bit better now since you have 183 images. You're picking image related numbers from a dropdown list and want relevant images added to the spreadsheet (destination depends on which dropdown list is changed i.e. E5 or G5). Do the numbers in the dropdown lists correspond to the numbers in the picture file names in your folder (so number 168 in E5 means add picture168.jpg, number 001 means upload picture001.jpeg or picture002.png or .jpg and so on)?

Comment: That's it exactly Mr. Igor you are right - that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Added and update to the bottom of my answer relating to your comment above. Hopefully everything makes sense as to what changes I've made. I tried to keep the changes to a minimum so it's easier for you to track and understand as to what needed to be done and make corrections if need be.

Comment: Thank you so much @Igor for your time and real help but i think there is still something wrong-what happen now is that when i insert a number in E5 it takes me directly to D44 without dislaying any images - I even saved the sheet alone in a new workbook but still i get the same result .I found another solution and it works (I loaded all images to another sheet in the same workbook and used lookup function to view the images in D44 or J44 ts ok but make workbook very slow because of the images size loaded and i need to load more. i dont know the broblem but any way thank u really for your time

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the Immediate window when you run into this problem? I think the issue is simply that the code is not finding the picture in the folder based on the number you selected in E5. Perhaps your picture file naming conventions vary slightly from the values you select in E5, G5 or vice versa?

Comment: could it be because there is no link between drop down list in E5 & G5 with the serial of images in the folder? even i remove the drop down list and tryied to add munber manually but no change...I'm not professional in excel but i think that the problem is in this issue (how excel know the the number i insert in E5 is related to the image number in my folder = here is screenshots from the file and the images folder nming https://file.io/albpotVUUwwT

Comment: this is my worksheet if you want to test yourself - https://file.io/8xhnnKAIghtv

Comment: It is working for me, but my picture files are named picture001.png and picture002.png. When I enter 1 into E5 and press enter the code goes into the folder in the specified path with the above images and looks for the first image with a name which contains the '1' in order to then add the image into Excel as a shape, as you can see in the screenshot I added just before the updated code. The images you shared aren't what I was looking for - the Immediate Window is inside the Developer View or where the code resides (to view it click on View->Immediate Window).

Comment: The immediate window shows all the comments/Debug.Print the code makes as it's working. which is helpful when looking for issues. My answer post has a screenshot of the Immediate Window in the initial answer at the very top, if you'd like to see an example of what it looks like.

Comment: Tjhis what i have in immadiate window : Potential edit in sheet: Permit cell: G5
 (Del old if exists: picture2 and optionally clear cell: J44)
Potential edit in sheet: Permit cell: G5
 (Del old if exists, Add the new: picture2 into cell: J44)
 (Adding the new picture2)
  [searching for a picture which name contains: 105 in path: C:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\]
  [(exiting sub): didn't find a picture which name contains: 105 in C:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\]

Comment: Could you tell me the file name of the picture you wanted to be added by selecting 105 in G5 (perhaps something like picture105.png or 105picture.jpg)? Additionally, the code should list all the files it found in the folder in the IM (immediate window) to help you debug issues.

Comment: yes dear to select picture 105 and it already exist in the images folder - my pictures are named 1,2,3,4,5,...etc till 186 now - do i have to do anything in cells D44 or J44?

Comment: Could you post the exact file name of picture 105 (perhaps 105.jpeg). Also in the IM, could you check if you see a corresponding line: [(found the following file: 105.jpeg in D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\)]?

Comment: Also, what type of dropdown are you using in E5, G5? List validation or perhaps something else?

Comment: Also, I just looked at the code in the workbook you relinked and inside the code in Sheet called Permit, could you change this line: path = "C:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\" to path = "D:\Desktop\Guards\Guards National IDs\" and see if that works? Or recopy my latest code (because I forgot to change Drive C to D in my initial update and edited my answer a few minutes or so later when I noticed that discrepancy in my code).

Comment: My friend you are great - you got the problem - it was the source path code it was C: not D: it worked once i changed it to D  - thank you sooooo much Igor for being patient and insist to help me all over the last days .........thank you man it works now

Comment: just one last simple issue - the images come to cells D44 and J44 with very pic size not the same cell size - what can i do?

Comment: If you'd like the images to be the same size as cells D44 and J44, we'd need to change this line of code: Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, -1, -1) '-1,-1 simply uses the picture's original Width and Height respectively

Comment: What about the image size dear? it's not getting the same cell size in D44 and J44 but floating with bigger size...? what can i do to make it come with the same cell size?

Comment: Try replacing this line of code Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, -1, -1) with Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Width, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Height) Let me know if that works, it should resize the image to the size of the destination cell.

Comment: it worked my friend but still one issue - D44 is merrged cells D,E,F,&H 44 and the same for J44 JKL 44 merrged so the image come with only sice of D44 which is a part of the merrged cell (can we fix that?) sorry bro.....

Comment: Try Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, 182, 95) There is a dynamic solution which I'll post later.

Comment: you are great man - done - thank you so much Igor for your real help and thank you really for being patient and replying to all my questions - case closed dear - thanks

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you. As promised try this line for a more dynamic way of determining the Width and Height of the merged destination cells (sorry about it being a bit long and sloppy):

Comment: Set pic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(path, False, True, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Left, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Top, ws.Range(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Address(0, 0) & ":" & ws.Cells(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Rows.Count + ws.Range(a(r, 3)).row - 1, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Columns.Count + ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Column + 1).Address(0, 0)).Width, ws.Range(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Address(0, 0) & ":" & ws.Cells(ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Rows.Count + ws.Range(a(r, 3)).row - 1, ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Columns.Count + ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Column + 1).Address(0, 0)).Height)

Comment: my friend - everything is great there is just one simple issue if you can fix it will be perfect - when I add a value in E5 or G5 and press enter it take me direct down to the image cell D44 or J44 not to the next row after E5 or G5 - can you fix that Igor please?

Comment: Sure, just remove this line of code: ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select

Comment: My friend, please there is a new issue ... today I have noticed a probelm in the image insertion, when I put any number from 1 to 99 it select images after 100 - for example when i put 4 in cell E5 it gives me image 104 -when i put 8 it gives me image 108 not image 4 or 8 ... but all images starting from 100 till 186 are ok good = this happened before i delete this row: ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select

Comment: now I fixed it - i chnged the images numbering to 001 instead of 1 and and starting from 10 to 99 i ad only 0 digit ----- it worked well and after delecting this row : ws.Range(a(r, 3)).Select everything is good - thnak you igor

Comment: Great! Glad to see you adopt a better file naming convention (i.e. 001,002). Consider going 00001picture.png and so on should the number of files grow further (though you could add the extra zeroes programmatically later on). There are also alternative ways to match the numbers you pick in E5,G5 to the correct file names, also programmatically, for example with regular expressions or other conditions dependent on your naming conventions. I hope this was a good learning experience for you.

Comment: update still not working Igor - only date is ok but image disappeared too

Comment: Most likely because of this line of code: Const base_name_pic = "picture"

Comment: how do you name your image files?

Comment: as before 001, 002, 011, 012,099 - but even when I select image No. 144 - 165 for example it doesnt show up in cell D44 or J44

Comment: ok, so your files are named picture001.png and picture002.jpg and so on? or maybe image001.png and image002.jpg? I guess what I'm asking is what is the constant part of the name of the picture file names: "picture" or perhaps "image" or maybe something else?

Comment: there are some images png and other jpg or jpeg but there is no text ("picture or image") in file name just numbers 001,002,003,004,005,088,091,099,100,101,102, etc

Comment: Ok, I posted an update which should work with your current configuration

Comment: Perfect as usual Igor - it works now - thank you dear freind so much

Comment: Great, if you need any additions or changes, just add a comment here.

Comment: Thank you my friend I actually need your help in another issue related to last modified date also**** I have a worksheet linked to another workbook and updating data automatically whenever I add new data or edit the existing data in the master workbook and its ok- but i need to insert last modified date to the sheet when it receive any update from the master sheet = I hope that you understood what I mean,,, I tried it but only update the date when i edit the sheet itself not the master sheet ....

Comment: Do you mean you want D11 in the Permits sheet to be updated whenever you change or update the Master sheet in another workbook? We can definitely do something like that, just let me know which cells to track in the Master sheet/workbook for updates/changes.

Comment: No dearnot permit sheet iits a new separate worksheet named (Short List) and it's linked to another worksheet named (Guards) to collect specific data - whenever I edit Guards workbook , the other sheet update itself automatically but i need to know the last date that this sheet received update from the master sheet (guards)- the code doesnt work with me unless i edit the sheet itself but when it recieve update from the master sheet it seems like doesnt feel it **** I use the same simple code of last modified - code  here in next comment

Comment: Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9:G500")) Is Nothing Then
      
     
Range("D4").Value = Format(ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save time"), "short date")

    
End If
    
End Sub

Comment: I see. Are these sheets (Short List and guards) in the same workbook or in different workbooks?

Comment: NO, different workbooks= but remember that as you know all the shhet full with formula in all cells to collect data from the master sheet - in G5:G500 i added =Value( - before the formula but also didnt work

Comment: Ok, so you're updating/changing the Guards worksheet in one workbook and want a date of change to be added to the Short List worksheet in another workbook, right? For that we could again utilize the fso/FileSystemObject to create a connection between the two workbooks. I'd need additional details to write the code though - would you like to connect over Skype, it might be easier to work that way with screen sharing instead of typing messages.

Comment: The two workbook are connected and working perfectly I dont have a problem with data linking between the two worksheets - it's only the last modified date is what i need - i  need the date in cell ("D4") to be updated whenever the sheet (Short List) receive updates from the master sheet (Gurads) thats all  ***  ok for skype https://join.skype.com/invite/G7LGdaPg4Io3